# Regex to get words or series of words that start with a capital letter or small word both

Tags: regex

I want to get regular expressin for both small and capital

[gstr1,GSTR1,gstr2,GSTR2,GSTR3a,GSTR3b]

I've tried :

```
[gstr][1-4][a-cA-D]|gstr[1-4]
```

but cant get the right solution.

Comment: What do you mean same word both

Answer (score 1):

You  need to ignore the case as follows,
just post fix 'i' to the regex

```
/[gstr][1-4][a-cA-D]|gstr[1-4]/gi
```

You can verify the regex here : https://regexr.com/,  put your regex and string  there and verify the result.